# How to filter an array using another array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, filter, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects that has "number" property in it, i want to filter this array based on the "number" property through an array of numbers called "filteredNumbersArray"

i tried this but it doesn't make any changes to the array

```
const remaining = phones.filter(
          (data) => !((data.number as number) in filteredNumbersArray),
        );
```

**const remaining** is the filtered phones array.

**phones** is my array of object, my object has a field number: number

example on data in phones: `[{number: 5}, {number:2}]`

**filteredNumbersArray** is an array of numbers. ex.`[1,2,3]`

i want result to be `[{number:5}]` based on the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to know if it contain an element

```
const phones = [{number: 5}, {number:2}] ;
const filteredNumbersArray = [2,4,6];
console.log( phones.filter( e => !filteredNumbersArray.includes(e.number) ) );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fgsrjnm6/

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) when dealing with `filteredNumbersArray`.

```js
const remaining = phones.filter(data =>
  !filteredNumbersArray.includes(data.number)
)
```